NUnit [TestCaseSource] causing [SetUp] and [TearDown] run multiple test as well
I don’t want NUnit [TestCaseSource] causing [SetUp] and [TearDown] run multiple following the [TestCaseSource]
I want it the [SetUp] run 1 time at begining, [TestCaseSource] run multiple times until the data set finished, and finally [TearDown] run 1 time after [TestCaseSource] finished.
How can i achieve that?
